# Generalized diagrams

Tags: category-theory, terminology, natural-transformations

Certain mathematical objects can be described as a functor $F : \mathcal{J} \to \mathcal{C}$ from a small index category $\mathcal{J}$ to a bigger category $\mathcal{C}$. For example, we can think of a graph as being a functor from the category $\{V, E, s : E \to V, t : E \to V\}$ to $\textsf{Set}$.

But to describe more complex objects, we need more that one category. Instead of $\mathcal{J}$ and $\mathcal{C}$ being single categories, we could let $\mathcal{J}, \mathcal{C} : \mathcal{I} \to \textsf{Cat}$ be diagrams of categories, and then look at natural transformations $\eta : \mathcal{J} \to \mathcal{C}$.

For example, to describe binary operations, we can let $\mathcal{J}$ be a diagram with a single category $\mathcal{J}_x = \{X, Y, f : Y \to X\}$ and a functor $\mathcal{J}_f : \mathcal{J}_x \to \mathcal{J}_x$ that maps $X$ to $Y$, and let $\mathcal{C}_x = \textsf{Set}$ and $\mathcal{C}_f = (-)^2 : \textsf{Set} \to \textsf{Set}$.

Is there a name for these "generalized diagrams"?

Comment: I don't know if you have other examples in mind than binary operations, so I'm not writing that as an answer, but you might want to have a look at so-called algebraic theories, or Lawvere theories. And maybe a bit further, limit sketches that are more general (but it's good to have seen algebraic theories first to get the idea)

Comment: Binary operations, for example, are described by comma category $\Phi\downarrow\mathsf{Set}$ where $\Phi$ is the functor $X\mapsto X\times X$.

Comment: I'll note that your description of binary operations runs into a problem. Namely that a natural transformation from $J$ to $C$ consists of a functor $J_x$ to $C_x=\mathbf{Set}$, a pair of sets $X$ and $Y$ with a morphism $f:Y\to X$ such that $C_f F = FJ_f$. Applying this last equation to $X\in J_x$, we get $X^2=Y$. Applying it to $Y\in J_x$, we get $Y^2=Y$. This last equation can't be true unless $Y=\varnothing$.

Comment: Another thing you might want to look at is operads. Binary operations should be described as the algebras of the symmetric operad whose $n$th set consists of rooted binary trees with $n$ labeled leaves, with symmetric group action permuting the labels. (This is a comment, so I haven't fully worked that out, but it should be something similar if it's not quite correct).

Comment: @FabioLucchini I think comma categories are a special case of this. A comma category $F \downarrow G$ where $F : \mathcal{C}_1 \to \mathcal{D}$ and $G : \mathcal{C}_2 \to \mathcal{D}$ would be a natural transformation from $\{S\} \to \{S, T, f : S \to T\} \leftarrow \{T\}$ to $\mathcal{C}_1 \overset{F}{\to} \mathcal{D} \overset{G}{\leftarrow} \mathcal{C}_2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your stated question, what might we call these generalized diagrams, I would call them diagrams of shape $\mathcal{J}$ in $\mathcal{C}$ in the 2-category $\mathbf{Cat}^{\mathcal{I}}$.

In the particular case that $\newcommand\I{\mathcal{I}}\I=\mathbf{1}$ is the category with 1 object, so that $\newcommand\Cat{\mathbf{Cat}}\Cat^\I\simeq \Cat$, then 
$\newcommand\J{\mathcal{J}}\J$ and $\newcommand\C{\mathcal{C}}\C$ are identified with ordinary categories and natural transformations between the corresponding functors
in $\Cat^\I$ are just ordinary functors from $\J$ to $\C$, which are ordinary diagrams.

We could make the following abstract definition.

Let $\newcommand\B{\mathcal{B}}\B$ be a 2-category, let $J,C\in \B$ be 0-cells (objects),
then the hom category $\B(J,C)$ might be described as the category of diagrams of shape $J$ in $C$ (in the 2-category $\B$).

In the case that the 2-category is $\Cat$, this agrees with our usual definition of diagram. It also encompasses your notion of diagram, since for any 0,1, or 2-category $\mathcal{I}$, $\Cat^{\mathcal{I}}$ is also a $2$-category.